# Java: what's the IP address of server in order to connect two different computers

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I've designed a small multiplayer game on java and have successfully tested it using local host ip "127.0.0.1" but now I want to test it on two different computers which are both connected to a Wifi network.

the problem is I don't know which ip address client need to use to connect to the server. i have used IPv4 Address (in cmd ipconfig) but they don't seem to connect.

Client:

```
public class Client {
    Socket client;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    public Client(String gameServer) {
        try {
            client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(gameServer),8888);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket server;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    public Server() {
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(8888, 10, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
            server = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("----->" + server.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            System.out.println("Successful connection");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

basically I don't know what to enter as the constructor of the Client class in order to connect these two computers.

Comment: In your server socket try to change your IP address to your local one given by `ipconfig` e.g. `192.168.179.5` and access this one with your client...

Comment: @0x1C1B I used IPv4 Address in Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 (in ipconfig) but again didn't work.

Comment: Wait your server is running on the same machine in a VM and the client is running on the real machine? I guess the problem is the VM configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to firewall being on. after turning it off, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that the generally software **works very well on your local machine**. So the problem is in the network connection and **not in the software application**.

If you are in a **same network** (for example two computer in one house), check if ports are open. if you are in the same network you should local ip address. Just use **sudo ifconfig** command for linux and **ipconfig**  command for windows.

**On linux** you can use nmap or telnet to check whether port is open or not:

```
nmap [local ip] -p [port]
```

**On windows** you can just test using telnet

```
telnet [local ip] [port]
```

If you are in the **different network** (for example you and your friend in a different house), you can't use local IP address. You should do  **port forwarding** via the **router** in order to find local machine. Off course you should use global IP address in this case.

Comment: nmap is an overkill for that task, is easier and probably already installed on the SO netcat: `nc -zv hostname port`